# When redux rerenders a view containing a StackNavigator it reset itself to initial screen

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation:

[image]
If i change the login property of the redux state when redux rerenders the View my StackLogin resets to initial state (If i am in the SignIn view it goes back to Login). Its like its not maintaining its own state. Maybe its something im missing about this library.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `login` prop changes, React will re-render your component. To determine what to render, the `render()` method is executed. Your `render()` method creates a new `StackNavigator` every time it is run. Therefore your `<StackLogin />` is effectively reset when the prop changes.

What you probably want to do is to define `StackLogin` outside of the Login class. You certainly want to do it outside of the `render()` method.